# Facebook Logout - Como deslogar a pessoa do Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk

A parte de Login está OK. 
Tive que adicionar um "Você não é x? Clique aqui para logar com outra conta" que chama a seguinte função:

```
function deslogarFacebook(){

    FB.logout(function (response){

    window.location.href = "login";

}); }
```

Ele está mandando novamente para a tela de login. Entretanto, ainda continua aparecendo "Continuar como X" (onde X é o nome da pessoa que está logada no Facebook) sendo que eu gostaria que ao clicar neste botão ele deslogasse a pessoa do Facebook também para que ela pudesse se logar com outra conta.

Já li a documentação do Facebook Developers mas lá so diz que há 3 casos quanto ao FB.Logout mas não explica como faço para deslogar a pessoa realmente do Facebook para que ela possa se logar com outra conta.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a solução e foi a seguinte.
Adicionei este código no window.fbAsyncInit:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function(){       
    window.location = '[sua tela de login aqui]'
});
```

E o botão sair do Facebook quando a pessoa quiser logar com outra conta:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

Comment: Top. Parabens ..